# Maven reports 'The desired archetype does not exist' when using archetype from bintray

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, bintray

First, I install archetype to my local repository:

```
mvn dependency:get \
   -Dartifact=org.teavm.flavour:teavm-flavour-application:0.1.0-dev-8 \ 
   -DremoteRepositories=teavm::::https://dl.bintray.com/konsoletyper/teavm
```

Second, I run archetype generation:

```
mvn -DarchetypeCatalog=local \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.teavm.flavour \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=teavm-flavour-application \
  -DarchetypeVersion=0.1.0-dev-8 \
  archetype:generate
```

and get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate
(default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist 
(org.teavm.flavour:teavm-flavour-application:0.1.0-dev-8) -> [Help 1]
```

When I build the project from sources and generate SNAPSHOT archetype, everything works fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or it's a bug in Maven? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to https://bintray.com/konsoletyper/teavm/teavm-flavour-dev

Then hit Set Me Up!

And choose: Resolving artifacts using Maven

copy this part into your settings xml (usually located in /Users/os-username/.m2/settings.xml see bellow):

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>bintray-konsoletyper-teavm</id>
                    <name>bintray</name>
                    <url>http://dl.bintray.com/konsoletyper/teavm</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>bintray-konsoletyper-teavm</id>
                    <name>bintray-plugins</name>
                    <url>http://dl.bintray.com/konsoletyper/teavm</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <id>bintray</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

Then try the second command again.

settings.xml:

There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml

A user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: This works! But what's the cause? When I download dependency manually, Maven does not see archetype in the local repository, even after I run `archetype:crawl`. Also, I have to explain my users how to update their `settings.xml` instead just providing single command-line snippet.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the problem is, but seems like mv noes not know to look at your bintray repository unless you configure it in the settings.xml. I have tried multiple command line arguments for the archetype:generate command, like changing the archetypeCatalog, with no success. Maybe adding a archetype-catalog.xml to the root of your repo and setting archetypeCatalog to your repos root/catalog file will help.
Also, take a look here, it might have some good knowledge.
https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html
Good luck...

Comment: As for your users, if you will link your package to JCenter and use binary's auto sync to maven central, I am guessing your users will not have to change anything in their settings.xml since all files will be discoverable by default maven clients.
https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/uploads/uploads_syncingwiththirdpartyplatforms.html

Comment: I use bintray to publish preview builds, which I don't want to publish on Maven Central.

Comment: It's strange. Even when I delete my local `archetype-catalog.xml`, I'm still able to use locally-built archetypes, but when I download these archetypes to local repository, Maven does not recognize them. Maven sees them as artifacts, but not as archetypes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the plugin "Maven Archetype Catalogs" that fetch for external archetype catalog files.

Go to **Preferences** by taping ⌘, (macOS), or Ctrl+Alt+S (Windows/Linux) then  **Plugins** and look for Maven Archetype Catalogs.